# Wild inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

I'm trying to solve this elementary inequality, but so far no clue. Can anybody solve it?
I tried am/gm inequality on both side, but yield the same result hence no inequality. Also I tried other tricks, but no answer. Any proofs or hint would be appreciated.This is the problem:

assume $a,b,c,d$ are real positive numbers i.e. $a,b,c,d, \in \mathbb{R}^+$.  prove that:

$$a^4b + b^4c + c^4d+  d^4a \ge abcd(a+b+c+d).$$

Comment: see here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h587349p3476518

Comment: the proof is not so simple

Comment: does this help you?

Comment: xD .thanks man! that was the proof using weighted am/gm. I also saw the other way of proof. thank you very much.

Comment: i don't see this way yet

Comment: @max8128 You can not because our inequality is cyclic and not symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{cd}\geq a+b+c+d.$$
Now, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{cd}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{acd}\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2}{abc+abd+acd+bcd}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that 
$$\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2}{abc+abd+acd+bcd}\geq a+b+c+d$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}a^4+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}a^2b^2\geq4abcd+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}a^2bc,$$
which is true by Muirhead because $(4,0,0,0)\succ(1,1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,0,0)\succ(2,1,1,0)$.

Done!

Comment: I know it's been a while, sorry to bring it out now. I can't understand the second step, how the cyclic sum of LHS is greater than RHS (with the sum of denominator)?

Comment: It's just the Muirhead inequality

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!